# JRadioButton that looks like JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, renderer, jradiobutton

I'm trying to create a feature similar to that of [Geogebra](http://www.geogebra.org)'s toolbar: it has buttons that select tools, so only one can be selected at a time, but they don't look like radio buttons (a  dot, with an inner dot if it's selected); they look like `JButton`s with an `ImageIcon`.

I've gone through some of the source (specifically [ModeToggleMenu.java](http://geogebra.uni.lu/trac/browser/trunk/geogebra/geogebra/gui/toolbar/ModeToggleMenu.java) and [Toolbar.java](http://geogebra.uni.lu/trac/browser/trunk/geogebra/geogebra/gui/toolbar/Toolbar.java)) but still can't quite figure out what's happening. I just need something basic. I would really appreaciate help!

Screenshot of what I mean:

[image: An image of Geogebra's toolbar]

Note the pointer, point, line, perpendicular line, triangle, etc.. That's the effect I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create custom icons then use:

```
radioButton.setIcon(...);
radioBbutton.setSelectedIcon(...);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the little thing that you missed is that the Geogebra code you linked to uses this as the button class:

```
class MyJToggleButton extends JToggleButton
```

So the buttons are JToggleButtons not JRadioButtons. JToggleButtons can be used directly and put into button groups just like radio buttons. Geogebra's code does custom painting, but you can just set an icon as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think I'd prefer to use the components for their intended purpose (for example, clicking the tool again does *not* untoggle the tool, as a developer reading the code would expect) – unless, of course, there is an upside to using `JToggleButton`s; is there?

Comment: There's a related `JToggleButton` example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/buttons).